# Bar plot using continuous variable and factor to color bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, continuous

I have a a dataset that looks like this but much bigger:

```
County <- rep(c("Alameda", "Clallam", "Clatsop", "Contra Costa", "Coos", "Curry"), each=2)
Habitat <-rep(c("Seagrass","Saltmarsh"), time=6)
Acres <- c(892.03, 6841.43, 5092.35,214.74, 0, 463.06,3165.39,2159.99,263.21, 12.53, 0,83.1)
SVI<-rep(c(0.4701, 0.6146,0.5185,0.4057,0.529,0.8774), each=2)

df <- data.frame(County, Habitat, Acres, SVI)
```

I would like to make a barplot that shows the number of acres for seagrass and saltmarsh by county but I would like the color of the barplot to reflect the SVI value.

So ideally I would have: bars in a range of shades of pink that reflect seagrass + SVI value and bars in a range of shades of blue that reflect saltmarsh+SVI value. I figured out how to do this for two discrete value but not one categorical and one continuous.

So far I have:

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=County, y=Acres, fill=Habitat, color=SVI)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

But that's not exactly what I want.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Annick

Comment: Because you put quotes around your numbers in your data frame, they are **not numeric**, they are `character` class. I'd recommend deleting the quotes or using `as.numeric()` to make your numbers `numeric` class.

Comment: Edited as per comment :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can use `alpha` to set the transparency, which will give you the result of a range of colors within a given variable.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=County, y=Acres, fill=Habitat, alpha=SVI, color = Habitat)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

[image]

Another option would be to use facets, which then allows you to vary colors more widely across `County` while maintaining the distinction between `Habitat`s. Lots of different options for color scales. Some info here: https://ggplot2-book.org/scale-colour.html

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=County, y=Acres, fill=SVI)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~Habitat) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]

---

Data, with a tweak to make `Acres` and `SVI` numeric

```
County <- rep(c("Alameda", "Clallam", "Clatsop", "Contra Costa", "Coos", "Curry"), each=2)
Habitat <-rep(c("Seagrass","Saltmarsh"), time=6)
Acres <- c("892.03", "6841.43", "5092.35","214.74", "0", "463.06","3165.39","2159.99","263.21", "12.53", "0","83.1")
SVI<-rep(c("0.4701", "0.6146","0.5185", "0.04057", "0.529","0.8774"), each=2)

df <- data.frame(County, Habitat, Acres = as.numeric(Acres), SVI = as.numeric(SVI))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to convert your character variables to numbers:

```r
df$Acres <- as.numeric(df$Acres)
df$SVI   <- as.numeric(df$SVI)
```

Using two fill scales for dodged bars is tricky. It requires two separate layers, which will not dodge automatically, so require a numeric axis that has to be faked to look discrete. It also requires two gradient fill scales, which can't be done natively in ggplot, but can be done using the `ggnewscale` extension package:

```r
library(ggnewscale)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = subset(df, Habitat == "Seagrass"),
       aes(x = as.numeric(factor(County)) - 0.2, y = Acres, fill = SVI)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.35, color = "gray50") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "hotpink", high = "white", name = "Seagrass") +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_col(data = subset(df, Habitat == "Saltmarsh"), width = 0.35,
           aes(x = as.numeric(factor(County)) + 0.2, fill = SVI),
           color = "gray50") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "navy", high = "lightblue", name = "Saltmarsh") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq_along(levels(factor(df$County))),
                     labels = levels(factor(df$County)), name = "County") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image]